# Why consider permanent DST instead of Standard Time?

Tags: united-states

I'm having a hard time understanding why making Daylight Saving Time permanent is being considered.  The net effect of keeping DST over Standard Time is that you have forced everybody to change their printed schedules by an hour.

I.E. If the hours of operation on the wall said 9 to 5, in the permanent DST world, they are really 8 to 4 (Standard Time).

So, why not just go permanent Standard Time and just send out an advisory that schedules should be changed to move all the times to the left by an hour?
Is it really easier to get everybody to change their clocks than to change their schedules?

Comment: I really do wish they would pick one and be done.  I hate the time change.  I'm still recovering from this weekend's change

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10745/why-is-nevada-asking-congress-for-permanent-dst-in-pacific-time-instead-of-adop?rq=1

Comment: @Roger Not really a dupe of that.  I'm not suggesting moving the timezone.  I'm suggesting that the current timezone stay the same and scheduled be adjusted.  IE When the clocks fall back for the last time, also make your schedules fall back with them.

Comment: Agreed, thought I'd aim to make solar noon equal to 2pm. In olden times, noon was the center of people's day (rise at dawn, sleep shortly after dusk). Now, it's closer to 2pm (wake at 6am, sleep at 10pm, or some variation thereof)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's much easier to change clocks. Or, since switching from and to DST happens twice a year, it's even easier: **you just tell people to stop changing clocks**.

Schedules are in people's minds, and sometimes even the language (e.g. 'a 9 to 5 job', '7-11'). That's much harder for a government to control.

Comment: That how Saskatchewan does it; our solar noon is always at 1pm. That said if we want sunlight times to match times when people are awake it's looking like we'd have to adjust it again as people keep sleeping in later and later ;)